# Не могу поменять отображаемый компонент - Angular

Tags: angular

С помощью ngSwitch пытаюсь менять отображаемый компонент:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentPage">
<div *ngSwitchCase="'login'">
  <app-login [changePage]="changePage"></app-login>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'registration'">
  <app-registration></app-registration>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchDefault>
  <app-default [changePage]="changePage"></app-default>
</div>
```

ChangePage - метод, который должен менять currentPage:

```
export class IdentificationWindowModalComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentPage: string;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: string) { 
    this.currentPage = data;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {  }

  public changePage(path: string): void {
    this.currentPage = path;
  }
}
```

Data в конструтор и Path в changePage приходят корректные.

Я также пытался менять таким способом, но это не дало никаких положительных результатов:

```
this.currentPage = 'login';
```

В качесте тестирования я также пытался менять currentPage в конструкторе через некоторый промежуток времени(n-ое количество секунд) - это работает, отображаемый компонент меняется, но сделать это через функцию changePage у меня не получилось.

В чем может быть проблема? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Зачем эти извращения? Роутер чем не устраивает?

Comment: @InDevX, конечно можно, но меня интересует конкретно эта проблема

Comment: Тут проблема в некорректном подходе, не вижу смысла подсказывать что исправить надо

Comment: Исправил 

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, добавив к вызову передачу контекста:

```
<app-default [changePage]="changePage.bind(this)"></app-default>
```